# Can we move SQL Server installed bit from default location to other drive

Tags: sql-server, ssms, installation, azure-vm

My client gave me command line installer for SQL Server. Since it is command line there is no option to select the installation path! So installer automatically chooses the default location `C:\Program Files (x86)` drive for installation.

I would like to move all the installed bit from `C:\Program Files (x86)` drive to to other drive. Can I cut and paste the SQL folders from drive and map the new location in Management Studio?

The below link says that SQL Server is dependent on C: drive.
[Installing SQL Server on not the default path](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/85912/installing-sql-server-on-not-the-default-path)

Requirement: I am using Azure VMs and attached extra drives. I want to make sure my SQL Server to be stable in case OS drive get corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method is (probably) to uninstall and this time run the command line installer again with a different set of flags and it will install to a different location unless you are talking about components not listed below.

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx

**Proper Use of Setup Parameters**

Use the following guidelines to develop installation commands that have correct syntax:

```
   /PARAMETER
   /PARAMETER=true/false
   /PARAMETER=1/0 for Boolean types
   /PARAMETER="value" for all single-value parameters. Using double quotation marks is recommended, but required if the value contains a space
   /PARAMETER="value1" "value2" "value3" for all multiple-value parameters. Using double quotation marks is recommended, but required if the value contains a space
```

**SQL Server Setup Control**

**/INSTALLSHAREDDIR**

Specifies a nondefault installation directory for 64-bit shared components.
Default is %Program Files%\Microsoft SQL Server
Cannot be set to %Program Files(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server

**/INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR**

Specifies a nondefault installation directory for 32-bit shared components. Supported only on a 64-bit system.

**/INSTANCEDIR**

Specifies a nondefault installation directory for instance-specific components.